# htaccess query_string condition does not work

Tags: .htaccess

I use this code to redirect all http to https, except if query param ssl=0 is defined:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)ssl=0($|&)
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

This code works on local server, but not on apache+nginx server. What is the problem?

Comment: RewriteConds are joined by an implicit AND; by putting the `[OR]` on the first one, you have that one joined with the second one with OR now; but the rest is still implicit ANDs. Do you need those conditions checking on the host name for anything in particular here?

Comment: That is intended: if ((http OR www) AND !"ssl=0") then redirect to https://example.com. Expected result is: redirect all to https except when query string contains "ssl=0". This works on local, but not on the server.

Comment: But AND binds stronger than OR, and those grouping braces exist only in your imagination ... effectively, you got (https=off) OR (host-condition-1 AND host-condition-2 AND  query-string-ssl=0) here.

Comment: I always thought that OR has higher precedence. Then how it should be written, can you please provide code example?

Comment: You might need to repeat conditions (A AND B OR A AND C), or split this up into multiple blocks. Do you need this to be dynamic regarding the host name? If not, I would do away with the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$` condition, _only_ check if the host name starts with `www.` - and hard-code the host name in the substitution URL instead.

Comment: I tried: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !(^|&)ssl=0($|&)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=302];    In the Network tab, it shows 307 redirect which doesnt make any sense. On localhost it works as intended

Comment: So no one on stackoverflow knows this?

Comment: It is hard to tell from the outside, we don't know if there is any additional configuration on some upper level. Maybe enable rewrite logging, and check what exactly is going on.